# Confusion between ASCII and int values conversion

Tags: java

How does Java understand whether to substitute char or int?

```
String a="abc";
int b[]=new int[100];

System.out.println(a.charAt(0)); //prints 'a'
System.out.println(b[a.charAt(0)]); //accesses b[97] and does not give error for b['a']
```

Comment: I suggest marking an answer as accepted

Answer (score 2):

The `char` is converted to an `int` using widening conversion. This is described in [this section about unary numeric promotion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.1) from the Java Language Specification, specifically:

> Otherwise, if the operand is of compile-time type `byte`, `short`, or `char`, it is promoted to a value of type `int` by a widening primitive conversion (§5.1.2).

Answer (score 1):

`Java` automatically casts `char` to `int` when an int would be used.

This is perfectly valid `Java` code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int field1 = 'a';
    System.out.println(field1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`a.charAt(0)` is a character, so it knows to print `a` in the first line.

In the second line, an index is always a number, so Java automatically converts the `char` value to its numeric counterpart.

That's not really a safe conversion because the specific numeric value of `a` might differ depending on your encoding.

Comment: Thank you. This helped. Yes, it will differ for Unicode and ASCII

Answer (score 0):

There is an [overload of `println` that specifically takes a `char`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println-char-).  This handles `char`s separately; without this overload, the `int` overload would still be present, the `char` would be promoted to `int`, and the `int` overload would print `97`, which is the Unicode code point (ASCII lines up for English letters, numbers, and common punctuation).

However, in an array index context, it is promoted to an `int` per [JLS Section 15.10.3, "Array Access Expressions"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.10.3).

> The index expression undergoes unary numeric promotion (§5.6.1). The promoted type must be int, or a compile-time error occurs.

Unary numeric promotion is what promotes the `char` to an `int`, so that it accesses `b[97]`.

It is usually best to avoid this implicit widening of a `char` to an `int`, to avoid something unexpected such as accessing `b[97]`.

Comment: Thank you. This helped. I suppose explicit type casting is better and simpler to follow

Comment: As the asker of this question, at your discretion, you may [accept exactly one answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) that you think helps you the best.

Answer (score 0):

This is inferred by the compiler. A `char` may be used instead of an `int`. The context of usage determines which one is used - the given types are preferred if there is ambiguity. However, if only the other type would work in the context (`b['a']` would obviously be invalid were it not for the conversion), this type is inferred.

Answer (score 0):

For the following:

```
System.out.println(a.charAt(0));
```

Java calls the method `PrintStream.println(char x)` since you are passing a character. So no problem there.

But for the following:

```
System.out.println(b[a.charAt(0)]);
```

Once again, `a.charAt(0)` returns the character 'a', but this time, since you are trying to get the element of an array, it will convert the character to an int, since you need an int to access an array element.